# delete de uma linha da tabela selecionada

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho a seguinte `div`:

```
<div id="div_conteudo" align="center">
<div id="header">
<input type="button" name="Delete" class="botao1" style="float: right; margin-right:-12%">
</div>
<div id="foot" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 440px; border:solid 1px">
<section id="s1">
<div class="div1" id="minhaDiv" style="float: left;"> 
    <table id="table" class="table table-bordered">  
        <tr> 
            <th width="20%" style="text-align:center">De</th>
            <th width="60%" style="text-align:center">Assunto</th>
            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center">Prioridade</th>
            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center">Recebido</th>             
        </tr>
<?php  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {  
?> 
        <tr>
        <th width="10%" colspan=4>Recebido: <?php echo $row["Data"]; ?></th>
        </tr>       

        <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row["De"]; ?></td>
        <td class="td-info view_data" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>,<?php echo $row["Para"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" <?php echo $row["Status"] != '0'?' style="font-weight:bold" ':' style="font-weight:normal" '?>><?php echo $row["Assunto"]; ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row["Prioridade"]; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row["Hora"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php  
        }  
?> 
    </table> 

</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

`JavaScript` para selecionar linha:

```
var tr = $('table tr:not(:first-child)');
tr.on('click', function () {
    var self = this;
    tr.each(function(){
        if(this == self) $(this).toggleClass('colorir');
        else $(this).removeClass('colorir');
    })
});
```

Dentro da `div id="header"` tenho o botão que será para fazer `delete` da linha da tabela, que está dentro da `div id="foot"`. Agora não estou a conseguir colocar o botão a `delete` a funcionar.

Comment: Não entendi... qual linha vc quer deletar ao clicar no botão?

Comment: @JrD a linha que quero deletar é a que selecionar. De acordo com a linha que seleciono, o botão tem de eliminar

Comment: E essa linha já está sendo marcada com a classe "colorir", certo?

Comment: @JrD sim, é marcada com essa classe

Comment: Você quer que a cada linha tenha um botão excluir ou um checkbox que você escolhe quais registros você quer excluir?

Comment: @Joao Benthin , eu não pretendo um botão em cada linha, pretendo aquele botão que coloquei acima, que está dentro da div header. Mas também pode ter opção de selecionar com uma checkbox as que pretendo eliminar. Veja aqui na imagem, seleciono a linha e depois clicar no botão [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj3DZ.png)

Comment: @Bruno Esse registro também deverá ser removido do banco de dados? Se sim, vc já tem uma função pra isso ou sabe como fará essa remoção?

Comment: @JrD mas se não remover do banco de dados, depois quando atualizar a página aparece novamente ou não?

Comment: @Bruno Sim, quando atualizar vai voltar. O problema é que, em minha opinião, o seu problema está muito amplo, teremos que desenvolver a função toda pra você... Vc tentou fazer essa remoção? Chegou em algum ponto que teve dificuldade? Se tiver coloque seu código, podemos te ajudar com os problemas e até melhorar seu código.

Comment: @JrD a parte do php eu sei como fazer, o problema é ao selecionar a linha como informo o botão que é aquela linha que tem que eliminar.

Comment: Por favor não edite sua pergunta com base em uma ou mais respostas. As perguntas aqui devem ser focadas, idealmente para que possam ajudar outros usuários. Se for o caso, faça uma nova pergunta, e nela dê os detalhes do ponto em que vcoê está.

Comment: @bfavaretto ok, obrigado pela informação, então vou remover essa edição que fiz à pergunta

Comment: Eu já fiz isso :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia é percorrer todos os `tr` que possui a classe "colorir", capturar o id dele e usar o [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) para remover da tabela, a partir dai vc faz a chamada para remoção no PHP

```
function deletar(){
    var ids = []; //arraypara armazenar os id's a serem deletados
    $(".colorir").each(function(){ //percorre todos os tr que possui a classe colorir
        ids.push($(this).find("td.td-info view_data").attr("id")); //adiciona o id da linha ao array
        $(this).remove();
    })
    //só fazer a chamada para remoção das linhas no php
    console.log(ids);
}
```

Basta fazer a chamada da função em seu botão

```
<input type="button" name="Delete" class="botao1" style="float: right; margin-right:-12%" onclick="deletar();">
```

Comment: editei a pergunta com o código, porque quando chamo o php por ajax, não está a enviar o Id, retorna sempre indefinido. Assim não remove na base de dados.

Comment: @Bruno Tente enviar com data: {ids: ids}

Comment: O ajax continua sem enviar o id da td, retorna sempre indefinido

Comment: O problema estava nesta linha `ids.push($(this).find("td.td-info view_data").attr("id"));`, então alterei para: `ids.push($(this).find(".apagar").attr("Id"));` e adicionei a classe apagar à `td`

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a solução possa ser feita com PHP mesmo. Esse código vai deletar todas as linhas que tem o checkbox marcado.

```
<form method="POST" action="paginaDelete.php">
   <input type="submit" value="Apagar Linha"/>
   <table>
       <tr>
           <th>Nome</th>
           <th>Sobrenome</th>
       </tr>
       <?php
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          echo" <tr>
              <td>".$row['nome']."</td>
              <td>".$row['sobrenome']."</td>
              <td><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='".$row['id']."' /></td>
           </tr>";
       } 
       ?>
   <table>         
</form>
```

Na página aonde fica o delete você tem que fazer o seguinte

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['id'] as $id)
{
    $delete = "DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id='$id'";
    $mysqli->query($delete);
}
echo "
<script>
    alert('Linha deletada com sucesso!');
    window.location.href='../suapagina.php';
</script>";
?>
```

Comment: mas no meu projeto o botão para apagar a linha fica no cabeçalho da `div`, logo não fica dentro do `form`

Comment: Você consegue fazer o botão fora do form  utilizando a tag form="idDoForm" no botão submite, como no exemplo abaixo:

<form id="myform" method="get" action="something.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>

<input type="submit" form="myform" />

Ou então utilizando javascript

Comment: sim tem razão, mas já resolvi com o código que tinha acima. Faltava me chamar a função `deletar` no `onclick` do botão